# SQL Join Query: Problem with multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I want to do an SQL join query. I have three tables _A, _B, _C, say. ANd each table has a column named "level" with some items having value 1,2,3 in this column.

At first, I just wanted an item with level = 1 from table _A, and so wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM _A WHERE level = "1" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

which worked fine.

Now, I want to select a random item with level=1 from any one of the three tables.
I wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM _A, _B, _C WHERE level = "1" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

It didn't work. The system crashed. But my reference book says this is the way to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM _A WHERE level = "1"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM _B WHERE level = "1"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM _C WHERE level = "1"
)
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: +1 Probably worth mentioning that the most likely reason why the OP's original query crashed his system is that he had inadvertently written a query performing implicit cartesian joins between 3 different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with redfilter. However, why do you need three tables for this Rather than having an additional column in table A (ABC char(3))? And then each row that would have been in table _B would have a B in this column and each row that would have been in table _C would have a C in this column. You can then use your first select statement unchanged.

Comment: The tables must be separated because they are used for a variety of different queries. And they are static, with no updating (theyre on an Android device) and adding values would take hours of time I don't have.